# nl without additional leading tab/space

Tags: text-processing, nl

I notice that there is additional leading tab/space whenever `nl` is used.

```
wolf@linux:~$ echo ABC
ABC
wolf@linux:~$ 

wolf@linux:~$ echo ABC | nl
     1  ABC
wolf@linux:~$
```

Is there any option to disable this?

Desired Output

```
wolf@linux:~$ echo ABC | nl
1   ABC
wolf@linux:~$
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `-w` option as following:

```
nl -w 1
```

to define custom separator:

```
nl -s '. ' -w 1
```

read `man nl` for explanation of the switches.

Comment: This will only work if there are fewer than ten lines in the file: it truncates line numbers with more than one digit

Answer (score 2):

You can try the `ln` formatting option

```
nl -nln
```

This will still keep the `Tab` between line number and text, but skip the space in front of the line number (but thanks only to left-adjustment of that column, so it may look ugly depending on your use case).

Result for your example:

```
echo "ABC" | nl -nln
1       ABC
```

Comment: the only disadvantage of this approach is that cannot define custom separator that can immediately follow the _numbers_ and it will start from next Tab position but well custom separator is not questioner's goal

Comment: @αғsнιη That is right; but this time I decided to refrain from guessing what the OP ("the OP" in the general sense) might have wanted in addition to the stated goal ...